# How do I obtain the application owner access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I send a User, Application or a Page Access Token, I get the following error:

```
"error":  {
  "message": "(#100) Only the owner of the app may perform this operation.",
  "type": "OAuthException"
}
```

How can I obtain an application owner access token for application/staticresources Graph API's?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to even ask this, but is the user access token you're using the access token of an Admin of the app?  It should be, as far as I can tell. 
You could also try the App Access Token, but the error message says it must be an app owner (== 'Admin' role)

Comment: The user access Token which i'm using is the Admin of the App.

Comment: Then this may be a bug, you should file it with facebook's bug tracker and include the user and app ids and the access token so we can check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should get the right access token, when you perform a call to /owner_id/accounts (with manage_pages permission). in return you're getting access tokens for all of your apps.